# OpenOCD with FT2232H on Arduino Mega (ATmega2560)

Tags: avr

I want to do on-chip-debugging on an [Arduino Mega](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mega-2560-rev3).
According to its [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), the ATmega2560 chip supports JTAG. (IEEE 1149.1 compliant)

Can I use a generic FT2232H interface to do on-chip-debugging on this?

How would a OpenOCD config file look like for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [chip](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232H.htm) seems to support it:

> Multi-Protocol Synchronous Serial Engine (MPSSE) to simplify synchronous serial protocol (USB to JTAG, I2C, SPI or bit-bang) design.

You'll have to play with the drivers,
and check to see that Arduino brought all the JTAG pins out to header pins.